# Expo.io - Module JSTimersExecution is not a registered callable module

Tags: react-native, react-navigation, expo

I setup a React-Native app using [the React Native offical docs](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/getting-started.html). But I keep getting this error message **`Module JSTimersExecution is not a registered callable module`** when viewing the app from Expo app in my iphone. The call stack is attached here.

[image: Expo error[1]]

I did some Google, but didn't find anything helpful.

Could anyone get this error before?

Comment: why dont you use the Expo SDK directly?

Comment: @EnriqueDev I just follow https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/getting-started.html

Comment: Try https://expo.io/tools, download their SDK and work from there. Way more useful, complete and with shortcuts to functionallity.

Comment: Solved your problem?

Comment: i  got the same error when i upgrade expo => 19.0.0 and react-native => 0.47.1 ,did you solved your problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I got the same error when i upgrade react-native to 0.47.1, I look the question and set react-native back to 0.46.4, it work!

Comment: This just avoids rather than solving :) See @Russell Maxfield's answer below for a working solution.

Answer (score 10):

Make sure to change `app.json` to the same expo version you have in your `package.json`. And also **make sure you are using the corresponding React-Native version the the expo version you have installed uses.** You may need to upgrade your Expo app. If that doesn't work and your versions match up:

- Stop your server
- `rm -rf node-modules` (maybe even remove your.lock file)
- `npm i` / `yarn`
- then start it up `npm start` or use expo
- then if you started up in the terminal Shift + R to restart package and clear cache, or press restart in expo if you are using that.

https://blog.expo.io/expo-sdk-v20-0-0-is-now-available-79f84232a9d1

Comment: Note in addition to updating the expo version in `app.json` I also needed to upgrade my Expo app on the Simulator itself (I edited this answer to clarify this).

Answer (score 2):

In package.json I set react-native back to 0.46.1, that seemed to work.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using cocoapods for your react-native project, remember to run `pod install` after you've upgraded react.

Answer (score 0):

Do you use Expo by any chance? If so, RN 0.47.x is not currently supported by Expo. ([source](https://github.com/react-community/create-react-native-app/blob/master/VERSIONS.md))

Comment: It is now with the release of expo v20

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this while upgrading expo when I had left the iOS simulator running.  A quick restart of the iOS simulator fixed the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I got the same problem with expo:20.0.5 and react-native:0.47.1. I upgraded react-scripts to 1.3.0. Then I restarted the Simulator and `npm start` and it worked.